# Widget Display Options in Magento2 - select all subcategories of category in one click

Tags: magento2, category, widget, magento2.3.4, sub-categories

Is it possible to select all subcategories of category with one click only ? I want to display my widget on category and all subcategories of this category. At this moment I must select every subcategory manually.
[image]

Comment: you want to only sub category or main category ??

Answer (score 0):

I want select all child categories of category by one-click. For example, if I have 100 child categories, I have to click 100 times. I want to select them with one click.